# How to check if LocalSystem account has read/write permissions to a specific local directory using C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-core

I am having trouble to implement a method that verifies if Windows LocalSystem account has read/write permissions to a directory because I just don't know how to instantiate WindowsIdentity class for LocalSystem account so that I can get the groups this account belongs to.

Answer (score 0):

This may work, not sure. Search the collection for where `rule.IdentityReference.ToString();` is `"S-1-5-18"` and then check the `rule.AccessControlType == Allow` and `rule.FileSystemRights == FullControl`.

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\temp\\");
System.Security.AccessControl.AuthorizationRuleCollection acl = di.GetAccessControl().GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier));
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < acl.Count; i++) {
    System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule rule = (System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule)acl[i];
    sb.AppendLine("" + rule.AccessControlType);
    sb.AppendLine("" + rule.FileSystemRights);
    sb.AppendLine("" + rule.IdentityReference);
    sb.AppendLine("" + rule.InheritanceFlags);
    sb.AppendLine("" + rule.IsInherited);
    sb.AppendLine("" + rule.PropagationFlags);
    sb.AppendLine("-----------------------");
}
String s = sb.ToString();
```

Here is a Microsoft webpage that lists out the [well-known security identifiers.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/243330/well-known-security-identifiers-in-windows-operating-systems)